# How to set title for UIButton?

Tags: iphone

How can we set the button title for a button,i know this answer its simple,we need to set the title of the button for title ,but my need is somewhat diffrent ,i had a username which dynamically changes according to login.i set this in a button click and display it in a label within that button .my code for this is

```
- (void)getFacebookProfileFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{

    // Use when fetching text data
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"Got Facebook Profile: %@", responseString);

    NSString *likesString;
    NSMutableDictionary *responseJSON = [responseString JSONValue];   

    NSString *username;
    NSString *firstName = [responseJSON objectForKey:@"first_name"];
    NSString *lastName = [responseJSON objectForKey:@"last_name"];
    if (firstName && lastName) {
        username = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];
    } else {
        username = @"mysterious user";
    }
     [_loginButton setTitle:username forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _lblfaceusername.text = username;


    [self refresh];    
}
```

i need to display the user name in another button click and have to assing the title of that button to user name the code for this is

```
- (void)refresh {
    if (_loginState == LoginStateStartup || _loginState == LoginStateLoggedOut) {
        _loginStatusLabel.text = @"Not connected to Facebook";
        [_loginButton setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        _loginButton.hidden = NO;
    } else if (_loginState == LoginStateLoggingIn) {
        _loginStatusLabel.text = @"Connecting to Facebook...";
        _loginButton.hidden = YES;
    } else if (_loginState == LoginStateLoggedIn) {
        _loginStatusLabel.text = @"Connected to Facebook";
        [_loginButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        _loginButton.hidden = NO;
    }   
}
```

i need to set the username in the `[_loginButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];`i want `[_loginButton setTitle:username forState:UIControlStateNormal]`;

Comment: Buddy... How you have created button. Paste the code..

Comment: Doesn't your approach work? What happens? Have you tried to call `setNeedsDisplay` for the hosting view?

Comment: [NSString stringWithString:username]; username should be object of class NSString.

Comment: ??? I'm not sure, if that's what you  want, but why don't you make `refresh` to `referesh4User:(NSString *)username`?

Comment: @dasdom sir i need to set the title user name for the _loginbutton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyhow you have set the button title in the method

```
- (void)getFacebookProfileFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
```

after facebook request done. Then, why you need to set that again in `refresh` method? Just comment out the line in `LoginStateLoggedIn` condition in `refresh` method.

```
//[_loginButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**Edit**

```
- (void)refresh {
    if (_loginState == LoginStateStartup || _loginState == LoginStateLoggedOut) {
        _loginStatusLabel.text = @"Not connected to Facebook";
        [_loginButton setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        _loginButton.hidden = NO;
    } else if (_loginState == LoginStateLoggingIn) {
        _loginStatusLabel.text = @"Connecting to Facebook...";
        _loginButton.hidden = YES;
    } else if (_loginState == LoginStateLoggedIn) {
        _loginStatusLabel.text = @"Connected to Facebook";
        NSString *username = [_loginButton titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_loginButton setTitle:username forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        _loginButton.hidden = NO;
    }   
}
```

Comment: i set it but nothing display in the button

Comment: if (firstName && lastName) {
        username = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];
    } else {
        username = @"mysterious user";
    }
     [_loginButton setTitle:username forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _lblfaceusername.text = username;

Comment: @Aadhirs i cooment out  what u say,i got the title in button after commnting the above line,thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

What you need is storing a reference to that message at a location that both pieces of code can access. The typical way to do so is to add a NSString * _username in your interface definition, and setting it to the username when you receive it. That way you can always access it from any location that depends on the current value of it.

Memory management included, that would yield:

```
[_username release]; // Release possible previous login
_username = [username retain]; // Ownership needed
```

In refresh:

```
[_loginButton setTitle:_username forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

In dealloc:

```
[_username release]; // Release ownership when not needed anymore
```

This allows you to access your variable at any location desired.